# TweenLite/TweenMax support for ConvolutionFilter

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

I am applying filters to a bitmap using something like:

`TweenLite.to(origBitmap,0,{colorMatrixFilter:{saturation:2,brightness:3});`

and that works fine.

I need to somehow apply a sharpen filter to `origBitmap` which I have successfully achieved using a `ConvolutionFilter`. The problem is after I've ran the above tweenlite call, then create a convolution filter and apply it to `origBitmap`, it removes the initial saturation and brightness filters and just keeps the sharpen filter

```
private function applyEffects(effects:Array):void
{
  currentEffects = effects;
  var props:Object = {};
  for (var i:String in effects)
  {
    props[effects[i].effect] = effects[i].amount;
  }
  TweenLite.to(bitmap,0,{colorMatrixFilter:props});
  //-- props could look like {saturation:2,brightness:3}


  //-- This will sharpen the container sprite
  var matrix:Array = [0, -1,  0,
                     -1,  5, -1,
                      0, -1,  0];
  var conv:ConvolutionFilter = new ConvolutionFilter();
  conv.matrixX = 3;
  conv.matrixY = 3;
  conv.matrix = matrix;
  conv.divisor = 1; 
  bitmap.filters = [conv]; //-- this removes the above filters and just sharpens the image
}
```

Is there a way to also incorporate the ConvolutionFilter in that TweenLite call above? I've searched quite a bit and found some guy made a class called TweenMan which was based around your class where ConvolutionFilter is incorporated: https://github.com/danro/tweenman-as3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to do with TweenMax here since your code is the one making the mistake. This correctly removes all current filter and apply only one:

```
bitmap.filters = [conv];
```

Since filters property is either null or is an Array. To add a filter to the list you use array operation and reapply the array:

```
var filters:Array = bitmap.filters;
if(!filters)
{
    filters = [];
}
filters.push(conv);
bitmap.filters = filters;
```

EDIT: starting over since I think I understand what you are trying to do. You are avoiding creating the filter yourself and let TwennLite do it for you even tough you don't need to tween anything. Don't do that, you are making everything harder for yourself. Instead create your filter that way:

```
var props:Object = {};
var colorMatrix:ColorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixFilter();
for (var i:String in effects)
{
    colorMatrix[effects[i].effect] = effects[i].amount;
}
bitmap.filters = [colorMatrix];
//etc .... then
var filters:Array = bitmap.filters;
filters.push(conv);
bitmap.filters = filters;
```

If you need to animate multiple filters remember that most tween engine can tween easily array values so you can just do that and then apply those array values to your filters.

Comment: I've tried that and it isn't working. I'd rather not use TweenLite, but the syntax for applying filters makes it so easy. I've also tried doing `bitmap.filters = [bitmaps.filters, conv];`

Comment: The tween is running at the same time and messing up the whole filters property. Not sure if TweenLite supports running 2 filters at the same time but either way you can easily do it yourself. I'll show you how if you need to.

Comment: why is the tween time set to 0?

Comment: I tried adding a timeout of 1 second to apply the convolution filter and no luck. I am simply using TweenLite because of its easy syntax of applying brightness, saturation and contrast. I am looking into how to apply those effects without tweenlite because I think I could solve the problem that way. The 0 second tween time is because I don't need it to actually tween.

Comment: then apply it directly in the filters property directly.

Comment: That is the problem. I haven't found an easy solution for brightness, saturation and contrast using colorTransform. That is why I went with TweenLite; a simple syntax for apply those filters I needed. I am doing this right now: http://pastie.org/10448670 after I push `conv` into filters it still says only 1 filter..hmm

Comment: I don't think `colorMatrix[effects[i].effect]` is a thing. `colorMatrix[saturation]` would be what it'd look like. It's hard debugging because I am loading the bitmap through an angular app so I can't directly test the swf in the flash IDE. I am using a lot of `ExternalInterface`

Comment: maybe this could help: http://chargedweb.com/labs/2010/04/30/fast_brightness_contrast_saturation/

Comment: if it's a prop that can be tweened then yes it's a thing. colorMatrix[saturation] would actually not work. Just try the code.

Comment: I did try the code. I got an error, but like I said its hard to debug since I am using the javascript console to debug since I cant test in the flash IDE. I get an error on this line `colorMatrix[effects[i].effect] = effects[i].amount;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90820/discussion-between-ronnie-and-botmaster).

Comment: while this isn't exactly the answer, you helped me get to the solution so if anyone sees this in the future, the answer is ditch tweenlite and simply use the `AdjustColor()`class which has brightness, saturation and contrast properties. You can then add that `AdjustColor()` var to a colorMatrixFilter via `new ColorMatrixFilter(adjustColor.CalculateFinalFlatArray());` and then pass that to your `bitmap.filters` array along with the convolution filter if that is a requirement